# Android Automatically generate java reference to xml ids using for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, foreach

How can I rewrite this code to generate java references for xml ids:

```
ImageView image11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block11);
ImageView image12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block12);
ImageView image13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block13);
ImageView image14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block14);
ImageView image15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block15);
```

and so on ... (100 items)
using for lops/foreach (and perhaps some string variables).
Thanks for reading!

Comment: what are you trying to do?!!

Comment: @AtefHares, he's trying to simplify some view initialization to move it to the cycle instead of a lot of similar lines of code

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes but he is talking about 100 view! I think whatever he is trying to implement can be done with `listviews` or `recyclerviews`

Comment: @AtefHares, oh, my... I've missed that 100 views mention in question. You are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `List` of `ImageViews`, and `findViewById` them by name, like this:

```
List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    int viewId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("block" + i, "id", context.getPackageName());
    images.add((ImageView)findViewById(viewId))

}
```

Comment: I changed context to getApplicatonContext to get rid of error. And also get error on last code line images.add(findViewById(viewId))
Error :

Comment: **add (android.widget.ImageView)** in List cannot be applied to (android.view.View)

Comment: cast it to the `ImageView` then. Same way as you do in your code. I wrote code directly in browser not checking it.

Comment: It works like that:
        images.add(i, (ImageView) findViewById(viewId));

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: But how to share images ArrayList from this code between all procedures code blocks? Thanks

Comment: Hey Vlad you are such a great person, can u share yr email/skype address?

Comment: @createcode, I'm not sure that I'm allowed to share my contacts here, but I use gmail, and my user name there is metalurgus.